# Register multiple dbcontext using autofac

Tags: entity-framework, ioc-container, autofac

We have application in asp.net MVC with DDD architecture with autofac IOC container. We are trying to register two dbcontext with different database connect. But the only last one is came in to effect. We are using Entity Framework 4.4.0. Here is the code.

```
var masterDataSettingManager = new SaasDataSettingManager();

if (masterDataSettingManager.LoadSettings() != null)
{
    var masterProviderSettings = masterDataSettingManager.LoadSettings();
    builder.Register(c => masterDataSettingManager.LoadSettings()).As<DataSettings>();
    builder.Register(x => new EfDataProviderManager(x.Resolve<DataSettings>())).As<BaseDataProviderManager>().InstancePerDependency();

    builder.Register(x => (IEfDataProvider)x.Resolve<BaseDataProviderManager>().LoadDataProvider()).As<IDataProvider>().InstancePerDependency();
    builder.Register(x => (IEfDataProvider)x.Resolve<BaseDataProviderManager>().LoadDataProvider()).As<IEfDataProvider>().InstancePerDependency();

    if (masterDataSettingManager != null && masterProviderSettings.IsValid())
    {
        var efDataProviderManager = new EfDataProviderManager(masterDataSettingManager.LoadSettings());
        var dataProvider = (IEfDataProvider)efDataProviderManager.LoadDataProvider();
        dataProvider.InitConnectionFactory();

        var dbProviderFactory = efDataProviderManager.LoadDbProviderFactories();

        builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new MyDbContext1(masterProviderSettings.DataConnectionString, dbProviderFactory)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new MyDbContext1(masterDataSettingManager.LoadSettings().DataConnectionString)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
    }
}

//data layer
var dataSettingsManager = new DataSettingsManager();
var dataProviderSettings = dataSettingsManager.LoadSettings();
builder.Register(c => dataSettingsManager.LoadSettings()).As<DataSettings>();
builder.Register(x => new EfDataProviderManager(x.Resolve<DataSettings>())).As<BaseDataProviderManager>().InstancePerDependency();

builder.Register(x => (IEfDataProvider)x.Resolve<BaseDataProviderManager>().LoadDataProvider()).As<IDataProvider>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.Register(x => (IEfDataProvider)x.Resolve<BaseDataProviderManager>().LoadDataProvider()).As<IEfDataProvider>().InstancePerDependency();

if (dataProviderSettings != null && dataProviderSettings.IsValid())
{
    var efDataProviderManager = new EfDataProviderManager(dataSettingsManager.LoadSettings());
    var dataProvider = (IEfDataProvider)efDataProviderManager.LoadDataProvider();
    dataProvider.InitConnectionFactory();

    var dbProviderFactory = efDataProviderManager.LoadDbProviderFactories();

    builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new MyDbContext2(dataProviderSettings.DataConnectionString, dbProviderFactory)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new MyDbContext2(dataSettingsManager.LoadSettings().DataConnectionString)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
}

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Comment: If you register two of them, what are you expecting to get? I am quite confused by your expectations.

Answer (score 5):

Register them like this:

```
builder
    .Register(c => 
        new MyDbContext1(dataProviderSettings.DataConnectionString, dbProviderFactory))
    .Named<IDbContext>("dbContext1").InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder
    .Register(c => 
        new MyDbContext2(dataProviderSettings.DataConnectionString, dbProviderFactory))
    .Named<IDbContext>("dbContext2").InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

And then resolve them:

```
IDbContext dbContext = ctx.ResolveNamed<IDbContext>("dbContext1");
```

If you would like to inject it in a constructor you may do it like this:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<SomeService>()
    .WithParameter(
        (p, c) => p.Name == "dbContext",
        (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDbContext>("dbContext1")
    );
```

Apart from having named registrations pf dbContexts you still can have unnamed defined in parallel with them - it may be treated as default one. Iy then in your application you would like rather to use a named registration then you specify this desire in the above way.

Comment: How would you inject the correct `IDbContext' in the constructor based on the name?

Comment: You can see this in my answer, this is the part: (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDbContext>("dbContext1")